# How do you update and change an object in ruby 2D?

Tags: ruby, ruby2d

I have a text object in ruby 2D showing score. How do I update the text?

I have this so far

```
    update do
      text = Text.new("Score: #{@score}")
    end
```

Instead of replacing it, it is creating a new text object on top of it. How could you replace it instead of adding it on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **[docs](https://www.ruby2d.com/learn/2d-basics/#adding-and-removing-objects)** it seems like you need to instantiate the `Text` object outside of the `update` loop. This will draw it to the screen "forever" until you call the `remove` method.

In your current code you are just instantiating a new object every time, and Ruby 2D is secretly keeping it around even though you don't have it assigned to a variable.

Unlike some other 2D libraries like Gosu, Ruby 2D does not stop drawing something until you explicitly tell it to.

Try

```rb
@text = Text.new("Score: #{@score}")
update do
    ...
    @text.remove # At a time you want to stop displaying that text.
    ...
end
```

[Adding and removing objects in Ruby 2D](https://www.ruby2d.com/learn/2d-basics/#adding-and-removing-objects)

Answer (score 0):

here a simple example how to use the `Text` class in `ruby2d`

```
require 'ruby2d'

sector = 3
txt = Text.new(
  sector.to_s,
  x: 10, y: 10,
  size: 20,
  color: 'white',
  z: 10
)

on :key_down do |event|
  case event.key
  when 'a'
    sector += 1
    txt.text = sector.to_s
  when 's'
    sector -= 1
    txt.text = sector.to_s
  end
end

show
```